# How do I get the frame of a subview in the ToViewController during animateTransition:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uiviewanimationtransition

I an using the new custom transitions introduced with iOS 7 and I'm trying to move a view from my 'master' view controller to a view in my 'detail' view controller kind of like how Photos.app zooms in on a photo when you tap on it except this view in the detail vc only takes up half of the screen. To do this I'm trying to animate this view to it's final frame by getting the final frame from the detail or toViewController. However the frame I get is the starting frame from Interface Builder for the toViewController's view and not the view that appears after AutoLayer has taken a pass at it. How do I get the frame after it has been set by Auto Layout? I have tried [self.view layoutSubviews] right before the toViewController special view frame is returned to animateTransition: but that still gives the IB layout.

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController* toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController* fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    [[transitionContext containerView] addSubview:toViewController.view];
    toViewController.view.alpha = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
        fromViewController.view.alpha = 0;
        toViewController.view.alpha = 1;
        fromViewController.specialView = [toViewController detailSpecialViewFrame];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];

    }];

}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?

Comment: @Alf Not a satisfactory one. It has been awhile since I've looked that this but I maybe recall calling the toViewController's view property in order for viewDidLoad to be called but I didn't like that solutions.

Comment: Thx. I got mine working using `toView.layoutIfNeeded()`.

Comment: Anyone intrested I found the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/48815089/5156056

Answer (score 1):

Call layoutIfNeeded, not layoutSubviews, to force a layout pass. Then the frame should be updated.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. At least not in my scenario. The frames are still as IB, not the final layout. Layout isn't correct 'til viewDidAppear which isn't called 'til the transition is completed.

Comment: It's a chicken and egg problem. :/

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/48815089/5156056