# UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning with Safe Area Insets on iPhone X

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit, iphone-x

When `animateTransition` is called on the transitioning delegate the Safe Area Insets have yet to be set on the 'to view controller'.

I've tried forcing a layout by calling: `toViewController.view.setNeedsLayout()` and `toViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded()` without success.

Can anyone suggest a means of either forcing the Safe Area Insets to be set early or determining how I should know the insets in time for the transition to work as it ought.

The effect is that I have a `UICollectionViewCell` that appears to move down once the transition completes. This is due to the frame having a `0,0` origin initially rather than say `0,44` on the iPhone X which it has eventually once the Safe Area Insets are set, by which time the transition will have completed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ensure that the destination view controller is actually in the view hierarchy when you call `layoutIfNeeded`.  I had this same problem, oddly only affecting certain orientations, and fixed it by adding the second and third lines below:

```
UIViewController * toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

// Added these two lines:
toViewController.view.frame = [transitionContext finalFrameForViewController:toViewController];
[transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];

[toViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
[toViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Wow! Can't believe iv'e missed it

Comment: helped me out too. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, do you mind showing the full code for the transition (or an example one)?
I'm having similar issues but didn't get to solve it with the offered solution