# Unable to get the correct frame for UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning to UIPageViewController

Tags: swift, uikit, uiviewanimationtransition

I have been battling this transition animation and I am pretty much out of ideas. I am attempting something similar to going from the collection to the individual photos in the Photos app on iOS.

It all works to my satisfaction with the exception that the frame for the "big" detail view of the image is not correct. It is the right size but it is about 87 points closer to the top of the screen compared to the actual position of the image in the final state. This is pretty much the same height as what is above the "safe area" (iPhone X titles + navItem) and irritatingly close to what is also below the safe area (toolbar and iPhone X home area).

I have Googled (and "SO'd") a bunch of different solutions to similar sounding problems. E.g: [UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning with Safe Area Insets on iPhone X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48624676/uiviewcontrolleranimatedtransitioning-with-safe-area-insets-on-iphone-x)

I have downloaded and perused example code from Github. E.g: https://github.com/SamStone92/CustomTransitions

It seems to me that I have something in my view (controller) hierarchy which is complicating this more than most. I would love some hints as to what might be causing the problem and how I might go about fixing it.

#### My hierarchy is:

- NavigationController containing the root VC with a UICollectionView.
- Tapping a cell transitions to a UIPageViewController for a "detail view" where I can page between items in the collection.
- UIPageViewController has a bottom toolbar in addition to the navigation bar.
- The content ViewController has a ScrollView with a UIImageView in it to get some zooming.

Seems like the common approach is to add the destination view to the container, force a layout pass and then get the frame. I have tried many variants of this with and without converting the coordinates. (they appear to always remain the same before and after conversion)

#### My Theory

I am leaning towards the UIPageViewController being the complicating factor. But I have not been able to untangle how to get the correct coordinates.

The destination view (in the animation) is not the content view but the PageVC view which in turn may or may not have added the content view, adapted it to the navigation item or the toolbar.

Seems like viewWillAppear on the content VC does not have the right coordinates. I can tell that the detail content view is getting a call to viewWillLayoutSubviews after that and also after all the animation delegation stuff has had its turn.

This is a color overlay of my main views. Grey is the top and bottom areas outside the safe area. Blue is where the transition animates to before revealing the green, underlying actual position it should have animated to.

[image]

Comment: I have ended up avoiding this issue by way of constraining my views (the relevant ones) to the window frame and not to the safe area at all. This is not exactly a fix but it does suggest that the more modern safe area calculations cause some issues with established techniques for getting the final frame bounds for a view when animating.

Still would love some explanation around how to handle these nested views and safe areas when transitioning.

Comment: I have the same problem with the UIPageViewController. My views align to the safe area, it worked when I aligned to the super view, when I changed it to the safe area is when things broke

Comment: Seems like a bug with safe area and layout